# Pass tmux selection to a shell command?

Tags: tmux

To have the vim-like, mouseless copy and paste in tmux, I have this snippet in my `.tmux.conf`.

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
unbind [
bind Escape copy-mode
unbind p
bind p paste-buffer
bind -t vi-copy v begin-selection
bind -t vi-copy y copy-selection
```

Suppose I've selected my text of interest. Now, instead of `copy-selection` with <kbd>y</kbd>, I want to edit my selection and echo the edited version to a local file with <kbd>g</kbd>.

Trying to pipe the output of `saveb` to a shell command, I tried the following,  but to no avail.

(forget about editing for now; just echoing)

```
bind-key g saveb - | run-shell 'xargs echo > ~/my-selection.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `copy-pipe`:

```
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-pipe "cat > ~/my-selection.txt"
```

Comment: Indeed what I was looking for! Thanks!